# when I play a mp4 video file in phonegap app on my ipad, it can't display, but it works in my iphone and the xcode simulator

Tags: cordova, video, mp4

Now I am developing a phonegap app, this app include some static pages which will play some videos in html video tag.

First, I use the xCode simulator to debug the app, it works fine, the video display.

Then, I install the app in my iphone, it also works fine.

Last, I install it in my iPad, unfortunately, the video can't play, it shows a 'video box' and a play button with a forbidden slash.

The code for video play in html is below：

```html
<div class="video">
    <video src="video/2.mp4" controls="controls" autoplay type="video/mp4">
     your browser does not support the video tag
    </video> 
</div>
```

Comment: The video type I use is mp4 and download from here:
http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/VideoSamples

Comment: What version of iOS on the phone and iPad?

Comment: iOS version is 9.0